# Two-way data-binding with ng-grid?

Tags: data-binding, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, ng-grid

How do I get two-way data-binding with ng-grid?

I am working from [their pagination example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#paging), and have figured out how factory and broadcast work; and have thus successfully loaded new versions of my data into the relevant controller.

How do I enable two way data-binding on the `myData` variable?

I have tried these two separate things:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = <injected object>;
$scope.myData = <injected object>;
```

What's the trick to enabling two-way data-binding on the `myData` object?

Comment: When you say 2 way data binding. What does it mean. As I understand ng-grid does not allow data to change from UI.

Comment: I want the data that is shown in the ng-grid table to change when a variables content changes in my controller containing the ng-grid code.

Comment: 2 way databinding implies changes from UI and changes to model are kept in sync. You are still talking about one way binding.

Answer (score 3):

It should work by default. I took the example plunker from `ng-grid` site and modified the content and it did automatic update.

See here
http://plnkr.co/edit/8St4ya?p=preview

See this code

```
 $scope.changeData=function(){
      $scope.myData[0].name="NewName";
    };
```

In case you grid is not getting updated on change in the binded data, the reason could be

- The object bound is not array.
- You are getting data in async manner (http call). Try to call `$scope.$apply()` after you get the data from server and update the collection

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of. I have very strange behavior: in two cases grid shows data correctly and in all other cases it shows blank although total number of items display correct number of items. I tried lots of different things including $scope.$apply() at the end of the procedure. Nothing helps.